# UILabel: adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth doesn't work

Tags: ios, uilabel

I want to make a string to fit the size of label. The code below doesn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
nameLabel.text = "fjggfjghggiuhgughuohgoihiohiohiughiugyiugyu8ftufuyguoy80houhuiy78rt6drtyreruti"
nameLabel.numberOfLines = 1
nameLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

Comment: try with sizeToFit()

Comment: use nameLabel.numberoflines = 0

Comment: what issue faced ?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik when I set number of lines to 0 then UIFont is too small, it looks like its default font size, not 30. But the text then fit to label size

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812192/how-to-set-font-size-to-fill-uilabel-height

Comment: Your code should be working. What need to do is to set a definite width of "nameLabel", by setting frame, or constraints in Storyboard or Xib.

Comment: @YunCHEN, I'm using constraints and the label has full width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIKit needs a hint about how many lines of text you want, or it doesn't know how much to scale down. If you want the whole text to fit into the label on one line, you also need: `nameLabel.numberOfLines = 1`.

Working playground example:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
label.text = "Some very long text goes here"
```

Comment: thank you. I tried to add this line, but nothing changed

Comment: Your initial font size is quite large. Did you try a smaller minimum scale factor, like 0.1? Is the `nameLabel` in the code properly connected to the storyboard?

Comment: yes, I've tried. when set numerOfLines to 0 it works. But when string is short UIFont is smaller than 30.

Comment: It only works if initially set the font size to a really big value (say 100). And numberOfLines should be set to 0.

Comment: Note the default value for [`numberOfLines`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines) is already `1`.